# Como o compilador trabalha no caso de um casting como este?

Tags: c, compilação, formatação

Tendo o código a seguir:

```
0    #include<stdio.h>
1    
2    int
3    main(void)
4    {
5        int x;
6        x = -3;
7        
8        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
9        {
10          printf("%d\n", (unsigned int) (x - i)); //necessita mesmo de parêntesis aq?
11          printf("%u\n", (int) (x - i));       //necessita mesmo de parêntesis aqui?
12      
13          printf("%d\n", x - i);
14          printf("%u\n\n", x - i);
15       }
16 
17        return 0;
18    }
```

Para compilar utilizei: `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -o test.exe test.c`

A saída do código acima foi a seguinte:

```
-3
4294967293
-3
4294967293

-4
4294967292
-4
4294967292

-5
4294967291
-5
4294967291

-6
4294967290
-6
4294967290

-7
4294967289
-7
4294967289
```

Duvida 1) Nas linhas 10 e 11 o compilador converte os tipos temporariamente para o tipo determinado no casting e posteriormente converte implicitamente para os tipos `%d` e `%u` ou simplesmente ignora o casting e formata direto de acordo com o especificador de formato ?

Duvida 2) O `unsigned int` converte um `int` com sinal para um `int` sem sinal. Mas afinal, como o compilador faz isso ? Observei que as saídas do código acima quando impresso um inteiro negativo formatando-o para `unsigned int` (no caso do código acima, implicitamente, nas linhas 11 e 14) a saída é um valor inteiro (diferente do desejado) que decresce  proporcionalmente ao valor desejado. Porque isto ocorre ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você chama o `printf` passando dois argumentos - uma string e um número - não tem como o compilador saber o que o `printf` vai fazer com eles; pro compilador, é uma chamada de função normal. Sendo assim, não dá pra ele ignorar o *casting* - ele converte o tipo primeiro, e então passa como parâmetro pra função. O fato dessa função converter de volta depois é irrelevante.

Quanto à forma de conversão, o que o compilador faz é simplesmente pegar os dados em binário - sem qualquer modificação - e interpretá-los de uma forma diferente. Vou dar alguns exemplos:

```
Sequência de bits                     Inteiro com sinal   Inteiro sem sinal
===========================================================================
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010            2                   2
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001            1                   1
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000            0                   0
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111           -1          4294967295
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110           -2          4294967294
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101           -3          4294967293
```

Ou seja, quando você tem uma variável inteira com sinal, com o valor `-3`, internamente ela é representada pela sequência de bits mostrada na última linha. Essa mesma sequência, interpretada como um inteiro sem sinal, corresponde ao valor mostrado na última coluna.

Por fim, um comentário em relação a usar ou não parênteses no *cast*: eu não sei se é necessário ou não, mas eu uso sempre, nem que seja pra deixar bem claro pro leitor do código a minha intenção (mesmo que esse leitor seja eu próprio, depois de meses sem mexer no programa). Ou seja, um desses dois é desnecessário:

```
(unsigned int) (x - i)
((unsigned int)x) - i
```

Eu não sei qual é, e nem me interesso em saber... Eu faço assim e pronto!

Comment: Sabe de algum documento que retrata minunciosamente como o compilador trabalha nesta situação ? A tabela que mostrou me deixou com uma dúvida, pois recentemente fiz uma pergunta que englobava isso e tive como resposta algo diferente disso. [Pergunta sobre assunto semelhante](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588541/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-if-the-parameter-of-srand-function-is-an-negative)

Comment: Pelas minhas contas (e por suposição), quando o valor é `signed int` o GCC (ou é a ISO que determina como deve se comportar ?) armazena os bits como complemento a 2. E quando é `unsigned int` o GCC armazena os bits direto sem usar complemento. Estou certo ?

Comment: @X0R40 Ambas as respostas dizem a mesma coisa, mas de modo diferente. O item 2 da resposta linkada diz: "repetidamente somando ou subtraindo o valor máximo mais 1". Ora, o valor máximo de um `unsigned int` é `4294967295`. Então `-1 + 4294967295 + 1 = 4294967295`, `-2 + 4294967295 + 1 = 4294967294`, `-3 + 4294967295 + 1 = 4294967293`... Se fizer as contas, verá que a mesma coisa vale para tipos de tamanho diferente `unsigned short`, `unsigned long` etc. E quanto ao seu último comentário, sim você está certo. A diferença é claro é só nos números cujo primeiro bit é `1`, os demais são idênticos.

Comment: Desculpa a insistência, mas então como as respostas dizem a mesma coisa, na verdade, o compilador faz toda a conversão (inclusive repetidamente somando ou subtraindo o valor máximo mais 1") em binário ? Isso tem alguma explicação para ser assim ou os implementadores do compilador que simplesmente quiseram fazer assim ? Teria isso algo a ver com aritmética modular ?

Comment: @X0R40 A especificação descreve de forma **lógica** o que acontece, mas na prática o compilador não precisa fazer nada, uma vez que o trabalho já está feito! E sim, essa é justamente a motivação por trás dessa regra "louca" de "acrescentar ou subtrair repetidamente" - porque especificando assim preserva-se a representação binária. E você também está certo quando diz que envolve aritmética modular: veja que `-1 === 4294967295 (mod 4294967296)`, `-2 === 4294967294 (mod 4294967296)`, etc. A própria representação em complemento de 2 foi inventada tendo isso em mente.

Comment: @X0R40 Só mais um detalhe: isso que eu falei vale pras arquiteturas "normais" (x86, x86_64 e outras), mas se alguém fizesse um compilador C para, digamos, um mainframe (que usa representação decimal em vez de binária) então de fato o compilador iria ter que fazer alguma conversão de valores durante o *casting*. Mas na representação binária, com o tipo *signed* representado como complemento de 2, essa conversão é efetivamente um "no-op" (ou, em outras palavras, a transformação de um tipo pro outro é a operação identidade).

Answer (score 3):

Dos teus quatro `printf` apenas 1 está correcto. Os outros três fazem Undefined Behaviour

```
   printf("%d\n", (unsigned int) (x - i)); // UB
   printf("%u\n", (int) (x - i));          // UB
   printf("%d\n", x - i);                  //
   printf("%u\n\n", x - i);                // UB
```

O tipo de valor enviado **tem de corresponder** ao formato de conversão especificado.

No primeiro `printf` especificas `"%d"` que requer um valor de tipo `int`; mas mandas um valor de tipo `unsigned int`.
No segundo `printf` especificas `"%u"` que requer um valor de tipo `unsigned`; mas mandas um valor de tipo `int`.
No terceiro `printf` especificas `"%d"` que requer um valor de tipo `int`; e, correctamente, mandas um valor de tipo `int`.
No quarto `printf` especificas `"%u"` que requer um valor de tipo `unsigned`; mas mandas um valor de tipo `int`.

Comment: Mas é muito comum utilizar cast dessa maneira. Vejo inclusive em livros. Os printf's que disse estar errado dão Undefined Behavior devido aos padrões da C90/C99 ? Ou é implemented-defined e o GCC que gera Undefined Behavior ?

Comment: Na primeira linha, `(x - i)` é um valor de tipo `int`, o `"%d"` requer um `int` por isso o cast é errado. Na segunda e quarta linha o `"%u"` requer um `unsigned` por isso é necessário o cast (na segunda linha o cast é completamente desnecessário por estar a converter um tipo nele próprio).